# Making a panel only available for certain URLs

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Chrome has something called ["Page Actions"](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/pageAction.html), and I'm roughly trying to replicate that functionality with the Firefox Addon SDK/Jetpack.  There's probably a better approach than what I've tried so far, and I'm open to suggestions.

Using `tabs`, I'm able to listen for tab ready and activate events, and if the tab's URL matches, the addon widget should be enabled; if not, disabled.  I've got to the point where I can change the icon when appropriate, but I'd like to disable the panel as well.

Strategy 1: Steal the click event and only show the panel if we're on the right page; otherwise, ignore.  Problem is, [according to the docs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.4/packages/addon-kit/docs/widget.html#detach), manually showing the panel causes it not to be anchored, [a bug that's not had much progress on it](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=638142).

Strategy 2: Set the `contentURL` to `null` when disabling.  Get an error whining about it not being an URL.

Strategy 3: Use a different HTML document for the disabled state.  Setting `panel.contentURL` to another URL doesn't work after going to a different page?

Here's the code:

```js
const widgets = require("widget");
const Panel = require("panel").Panel;
const tabs = require("tabs");
const data = require("self").data;
const prefs = require("simple-prefs").prefs;

var panel = Panel({
    width: 480,
    height: 640,
    contentURL: data.url("panel.html"),
    contentScriptFile: [data.url('jquery.min.js'), data.url('panel.js')],
    onMessage: function (msg) { console.log(msg) }
});

var widget = widgets.Widget({
    id: "icon",
    label: "Export",
    contentURL: data.url("icon.png"),
    panel: panel
});


function enable() {
    widget.contentURL = data.url('icon.png');
    panel.contentURL = data.url("panel.html");
}

function disable() {
    widget.contentURL = data.url('icon_disabled.png');
    panel.contentURL = data.url("panel_disabled.html");
}

function on_change_tab(tab) {
    console.log(tab.url);
    if (/http:\/\/example.com\/.*/.exec(tab.url)) {
        console.log('ENABLE');
        enable();
    } else {
        console.log('DISABLE');
        disable();
    }
    console.log(panel.contentURL);
}
tabs.on('ready', on_change_tab);
tabs.on('activate', on_change_tab);
```

Related, but should have the anchoring problem? [How to reload a widget popup panel with firefox addon sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098828/how-to-reload-a-widget-popup-panel-with-firefox-addon-sdk)

Answer (score 2):

In case you still haven't solved your issue (and for anyone else having a similar problem):

I had a similar issue and resolved it by using erikvold's [ToolbarButton](https://github.com/erikvold/toolbarbutton-jplib/) package. Once you've installed that and its dependencies, something like this in your main.js file should work.

```js
var pan = require("panel").Panel({
    width: 400,
    height: 600,
    contentURL: "http://stackoverflow.com"
    //maybe some more options here
});
var button = require("toolbarbutton").ToolbarButton({
    id: "myButton",
    label: "My Button",
    image: data.url("someicon.png"),
    panel: pan //This binds the panel to this toolbarbutton
});
```

I hope you can find some way to adapt this to your project.

Answer (score 0):

toolbarbutton.ToolbarButton({
        id: "MyAddon",
        label: "My Addon",
        tooltiptext: "My Addon Tooltip",
        image: data.url("logo.png"),
        onCommand: function() {

```
         var dictionary_panel = require("panel").Panel({
         width:630,
         height:600,
         contentURL: data.url("HtmlPage.html"),
         contentScriptWhen: 'ready',
         contentScriptFile: [data.url("style.css"),data.url("jquery-1.7.1.js"),
                  data.url("javascriptquezz.js"),data.url("create.js")]
```

});

```
        dictionary_panel.show();
```

}
});